# spring config client - Could not resolve placeholder 'message' in value “${message}” error while starting client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I am implementing `spring config server`. My config server starts fine and I can get the data from URL `http://localhost:8888/client-config/development` located at `C:\\configprop` as shown below.

```
{
    "name": "client-config",
    "profiles": [
        "development"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": "0dec53953ad4f620031cdbb3a99a0fe9701fb9df",
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "C:\\\\configprop/file:C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config-repo-5116664058083487059\\client-config-development.properties",
            "source": {
                "msg": "Hello world - this is from config server - Development Environment"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but when I get the data in the `config client` using `http://localhost:8080/message` I am getting `Could not resolve placeholder 'message' in value "${message}"` error.

***Client Application***

**Main Class**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**controller class**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RefreshScope
@RestController
public class MessageRestController {

    @Value("${message}")
    private String message;

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

**aplication.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: client-config
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
  profiles:
    active: development
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: refresh
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config-client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**client-config-development.properties**

```
message = Hello world - this is from config server - Development Environment
```

Comment: do you have a 'message:this is my message' or similar in your application.properties file? that is what it's looking for

Comment: message property is defined in the `client-config-development.properties`

Comment: and how does that file look like? are you using other properties that are in that file, that do work?

Comment: @Stultuske I have added `client-config-development.properties`

Comment: so, there are no other properties in there. probably, it doesn't find your properties file. You are pointing to a fixed path: "c:\ ... " especially since you're working on a server, you should not do that.

Comment: I am using local repository configuration

Comment: @SSK I am also facing the same issue here, If you found any answer please ping me.  Here is my question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143361/spring-cloud-config-with-database-backend

Answer (score 1):

According to the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes) for spring cloud 2020.0, there were breaking changes.

You need to add the following to application.yml

```
spring.config.import="configserver:"
```

Comment: I have tried `spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888` still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Hey can Inject this property by this

Step-1
Create a Class Like this and In ConfigurationProperties pass application property path a prefix

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.xyz")
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
public class LoginProperties {

    private String message;
    
}
```

At Application property

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LoginProperties.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

In Your application.yml Property file you might have this type of value

```
app:
    xyz:
      message: "Hello Java"
```

IN Your MessageRestController class

> @Autowired private LoginProperties loginProperties;

then try

```
 @GetMapping("/message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return loginProperties.getMessage;
    }
```

Or else you can directly try this way but am not sure

```
@GetMapping("/message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return `${message}`;
    }
```

Comment: I can't use the above configuration as I need to add more properties there like DB configuration

Comment: there will no issue even if you 100 more property  like even i also have lots of other property  like u

Comment: but here we are trying to bootstrap only mssage here, its not effect any or your flow or code

Comment: Agree but I will face the same issue again for DB properties as I will use just @Value annotation there

Comment: Can you try this way  if its work  am add at last

Comment: Even i tried to use as you  showing in question and on my side it working fine

Comment: Have you use `` or ""

Comment: Reading from property and as @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
 String value;    -------------------------------------      

public String test() {
  return value;
 }

Comment: Getting ` Error creating bean with name 'loginProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'message' in value "${message}"`

Comment: if you not using loginProperties then remove it  i just talking about your code

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class TestController {

    @Value("${prop1:default}")
    private String name;

    @Value("${prop2:default}")
    private String version;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/PropTest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getName() {
        return prop1+" - "+prop1;
    }
}

In bootstrap.yml add below with other properties
spring:
  config:
    import: configserver:http://localhost:8080/config-service

This worked for me. you can try this.
```